# Print source code from Spyder without turning off darkmode

Tags: python, spyder

Whenever I want to print my source code to a PDF in Spyder so I can hand it in for an assignment, I need to turn off darkmode (which requires restarting Spyder), then print, and then turn darkmode back on. If I keep darkmode on, the code will have minimal contrast with the background, leaving pieces of code unreadable. Is there a better way to do this or is it just a bug in Spyder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a [very old bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2521) that (unfortunately) we've been unable to fix until October 2020.

Please keep track of that bug to know when it is fixed (we'll try to do it before the end of the 2020).

Comment: Is there a better workaround besides temporarily changing the theme?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there are no workarounds for that at the moment.